# Id_token claims

Tags: adal, adal.js

I have an AngularJS application that I've successfully authenticated against ADFS 4.0 using adal.js.

Everything works well but the claims in the id_token do not contain enough information about the user to hide pieces of the application the user shouldn't have access too. What is the correct way to optain the group's the user is part of in the token? Or am I going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, we can add the custom claims about group info the users belonged to to the access token like config below:
[image]

Then in the back end of the web API, we can verify whether the request associate access token could access the specific web API.

Comment: Thank you for this. This lead me in the correct direction and I found this: 

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/development/customize-id-token-ad-fs-2016 

This let me up put the group in the claims

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me, I wasn't able to obtain the **Custom Claims** in Adal.js (Angular JS) from Windows Server 2016 (ADFS), using scope=openid. I just receive the basic information. Did I need to do something different/special/additional?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ADFS, but if you were to authenticate against Azure AD, you would not just have the id_token, but use that to get an access token to the application. The access token would contain the user's roles in the application, and you would use that to verify access to parts of the application.